# n*n (not nested) for loop complexity

Tags: time-complexity, space-complexity

I know that the pattern for algorithm complexity when looking at nested loops is generally `n^(m+1)`, where m is the loop nesting factor (loop within a loop).

But what about this simple case, where

```
for (i=0; i<n*n; i++) {
    ...
}
```

is the complexity `O(n^2)`?

Because the amount of executions is the same as it would be for a normal nested for loop.

Comment: complete your question, please!

Comment: Sorry, the post glitched out when the code part started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the work done in each iteration of the for loop is O(1) then the complexity of the for loop is indeed O(n^2) since you iterate n^2 times. And yes, you assume correctly it would be of the same complexity as:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. And if the work done in each iteration in this for loop is O(n) then I assume the total complexity would be O(n^3) etc. Correct?